# Making curl API calls with powershell

Tags: powershell, soti

I'm having trouble getting specific API calls to work in powershell using Invoke-restmethod. 
Specifically passing the -d "\"\\RootFolder\New folder\"" variable.
Example of the Curl API command for moving device groups:

```
curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer Very long token" -d "\"\\\\RootFolder\\New folder\"" "https://SOTIServer.com:443/MobiControl/api/devicegroups/%255C%255CRootfolder%255COld%2520folder%255CSourceFolder/path"
```

The Powershell call that I have so far, that doesn't work:

```
$folderX="SourceFolder"

function MoveDir ([string]$Name, [string]$Token)
{
    $Path = "%255C%255CRootfolder%255COld%2520folder%255C" + $folderX
    $body = "\\\\RootFolder\\New Folder"
    $body = $body | ConvertTo-Json
    $MCFQDN = "https://SOTIServer.com:443"

    $Header2 = @{}
    $Header2["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + $Token

    try
    {
        $response2 = Invoke-restmethod -Uri https://$MCFQDN/mobicontrol/api/devicegroups/$Path/path -ContentType "application/json" -Method PUT -Body $body -Headers $Header2
    }
    catch
    {
        $($_.Exception.Message)
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `curl` call, you're using `PUT`, yet you changed your method to `POST` in your other example

Comment: Nice catch, that is definitely a step in the right direction, now I'm only getting a "(401) Unauthorized" error.